# Does Django have any plans to drop support for Python 2 in the near future?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x

For new projects in Django, is it OK to use Python 2.7 or should I start with Python 3.x in anticipation of Python 2 support being discontinued?

Approximately how long will Django continue to support the Python 2 branch?

Comment: This is something you'll have to ask the Django project maintainers, not us.

Comment: If you could not find any date, that probably means there are *no plans to drop support*.

Comment: My answer is: "too late, or at least not soon enough".

Comment: @MartijnPieters did they announce when they were going to drop python 2.6 in django 1.7?

Comment: Why is this on hold as "primarily opinion-based"? It may be off-topic, but there is a verifiable answer on the Django website about their status with Python 2...

Comment: @electrometro Yes, it says right at the top of the [Django 1.7 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/) that it requires **2.7 or above**. These notes are published well in advance of the release, particularly so in the case of 1.7 which was delayed more than half a year from its initially proposed date.

Comment: @electrometro: yes, the [release notes for 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/) state it is the last release to support 2.6.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: we cannot answer the question as there are no plans to drop 2.7 support. The 1.8 release notes don't mention that it is the last release to support 2.7 (like 1.6 did for 2.6). Thus, predicting when Django is to drop 2.7 support requires a crystal ball.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Although the question directly asks the date for it, the spirit of the question is "should I ditch Python 2 if I'm sticking with Django?" and the answer is, objectively, verifiably, "no" at this stage.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: then you may want to edit the question into a better shape. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Django 1.8 supports Python 2.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/), and it has been [designated a long-term release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#lts-releases) guaranteeing 3 years of support from its release (currently scheduled April 2015).

Therefore, Django is committed to support at least the latest version of Python 2 until some time in 2018.

---

## Update

The following information is on the [Django Roadmap](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/) (h/t to @RemcoGerlich in comments), and is still current as of today (2015-11-09), regarding keeping Python 2 support until 2020, when Python 2 support will actually be discontinued by Python itself. In other words, as of now, as long as there is a Python 2, Django will continue to support it.

> As a final heads up, Django 1.11 is likely to be the last version to support Python 2.7 as it will be supported until the end of Python 2 upstream support in 2020. We’ve adopted a Python version support policy as follows:
>
> > We will support a Python version up to and including the first Django LTS release whose security support ends after security support for that version of Python ends. For example, Python 3.3 security support ends September 2017 and Django 1.8 LTS security support ends April 2018. Therefore Django 1.8 is the last version to support Python 3.3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This really shed some insight and helped me find my way through the django documentation a bit better.

Comment: According to the latest roadmap at https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/ , it is currently considered likely that 1.11 will be the last version to support Python 2 (because its LTS support will end in 2020, which is also when Python 2's security support is scheduled to end).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Cool! Thanks for updating this. That is good information. :)

Comment: Django 2.0 is now in their master branch. Python 3.5 or higher is required. I suspect they will maintain 1.11 for a while though. One important reason is that the memory footprint of dictionaries are much lower in versions from 3.5.

Comment: @Grimmy The [dict changes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) are in Python 3.6+. I suspect a minimum requirement of Python 3.5 has more to do with either coroutines or type hints.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist dicts were optimised in 3.5 as well. 3.6 takes it even further. What you say about coroutines make a lot of sense. The urge to get to 3.6 is probably related to both coroutines and dicts being superior in that version.